# Connecting Azure container app Spring boot backend to Azure container app Neo4j database

Tags: database, spring-boot, azure, neo4j, containers

I used the base neo4j image and deployed it to Azure as a serverless container app. Now apperantly an Azure container app can only use TCP protocol between containers in the cluster and not expose it to the outside. Since Neo4j uses BOLT protocol which uses TCP I need to also turn the backend into an container app so that it can access the TCP port of the database container. I send a spring boot image to Azure container registry which contains the link to the database and the base username and password neo4j/neo4j used by the image (I know I know i will turn those into environment variables once it works).
At first it gave error with the connection link but i fixed that so i know the connection is correct. Now i get an authentication error like this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKjX8.png)
Does anybody have experience with a similar setup? I am also unable to access the Neo4j dashboard because i cannot expose the HTTP 7474 port for the dashboard aswell as the TCP 7678 port for the BOLT protcol at the same time and the dashboard goes through BOLT.

I changed the password and username trying different options, no success.